# Is there a way to create two colors dashed stroked svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

Source svg circle of dashed stroke:

```
<svg width="996" height="996" viewBox="0 0 996 996" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="498" cy="498" r="477" stroke="#FBF4B6" stroke-width="42" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="7 20"/>
</svg>
```

Expected result (both colors are separated by the correct angle):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq2l4.png)

I've tried to add linear gradient for stroke, it works but separates the colors without correct circle angle

```
<svg width="996" height="996" viewBox="0 0 996 996" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ADC3F2"></stop>
      <stop offset="42%" stop-color="#ADC3F2"></stop>
      <stop offset="42%" stop-color="#FBF4B6"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FBF4B6"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="498" cy="498" r="477" stroke="url(#gradient)" stroke-width="42" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="7 20"></circle>
</svg>
```